# Add third party library in chromium project

Tags: android, chromium, intercom, gn

I'm working on an Android project that extends chromium project.
I want to add a third party library (www.intercom.com). The problem is that the intercom documentation is just for gradle projects, and chromium is not using gradle so I have to add the library manual.

I've tried to copy all the .aar and .jar files in third_party/intercom and create a gn file, but  I get an error:

```
Class "kotlin/coroutines/Continuation" not found on any classpath. Used by class "io/intercom/retrofit2/RequestFactory$Builder"
```

I've include org_jetbrains_kotlin_kotlin_stdlib_java, but still get the same error.

Questions:

1. Should I include anything else to get rid of this error?
2. Is there any automated tool/script, that generates a gn file for a library?

Thanks!